# Most efficient way to collect and save large amounts of data in background in android

Tags: android, multithreading, save

I'm building an Android application that accepts data from a variety of different sensors (5 in total) each providing acceleration & gyro, and one sending EMG data as well. This is happening all over bluetooth v4.1 at a rate of around 50Hz.

I need to listen to all these sensors in the background and save the data.

I want to know:

1) What is the most efficient way to save the data to disk ?

For reference all the data from all sensors amounts to around 23Mb per hour. Should I save the data in a file constantly (I doubt it), every hour etc. ? and is it inexpensive to data the data in text form, or should I save it as a large float array or something ?

2) What is the most efficient way to handle this type of background task ?

There does seem to be a fair amount of discussion around this. I've read about the following classes:

- Service
- IntentService
- HandlerThreads
- AsyncTask
- ThreadPool

Its really not clear to me which one I should use for this type of work. If someone more enlightened than me could comment I'd be very grateful.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first item, you obviously have to make a judgement call about how much data you'll willing to risk if the app gets stopped for some reason. The longer you save up data in a buffer, the more that will be lost in a crash. I don't see any reason to not append the data to a file as you obtain it.

As for deciding on the best format for the data, some things to consider are:

- What will you be doing with the data? Some formats (CSV text, JSON, etc.) will be easier for your downstream processes to use than others.
- If you're trying to write out the data as you obtain it, you'll probably want to minimize the amount of pre-processing required.
- Some formats, such as the XML-based ones, are much less efficient space-wise than others. The smallest would probably be a binary format.

In addressing the second item a bit, the two Service items are useful if you want the process to keep working in the background; otherwise your app has to remain in the forefront. Since yours would be running for a long time, you'd probably want to use IntentService.

The other items are just different ways to run things on a thread separate from your main thread. The AsyncTask makes it easy to run stuff where you want progress feedback and where you want to use the eventual results to update your GUI.

Handlers *can* be run on other threads, but are typically just used to run stuff at different times on the main thread. This is done by posting (optionally delayed) messages to a message queue.

ThreadPool and other threading constructs are much more low level. It's a roll-your-own approach where you have more fine-tune control, but have to do much most of the house-keeping work manually.

A couple of useful pages are [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and [Android Thread Constructs (Part 4): Comparisons](http://techtej.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html).

Comment: *Since yours would be running for a long time, you'd probably want to use IntentService* nope, regular service is the way to go

Comment: From what I've read IntentService does seem to be the option. Most people stress that Services shouldn't be used to long periods of time